# How do i get a smart contract to interact with a website?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design, remix

I have a site, let's say a user solves a game, i want that user to be stored in a database that represents users who solved the game, users stored in this database will then be able to redeem tokens.

How do i establish the connection that the user solved the game and is now eligible to be stored in this database?

Answer (score 2):

First, think in terms of what the blockchain/smart contract component of this is meant to prove. There are two obvious approaches:

1. The contract decides the winner. In this approach, the contract itself enforces the rules of the game and web server and/or browsers defer to its decision.
2. The contract records that an authority, say ... the web server, simply deemed that a given player is the winner of a given round. There is no evidence of an honest game in the contract, but there is a proof that the server signed a transaction to award the prize.

The choice will determine the structure of the contract in non-trivial ways.

Some very simplified sketches for illustration only:

Method 1:

```
contract Game {
  address[] public winners;
  function submitWinningMove(bytes32 move) public returns(bool success) {
    require(gameIsOn());
    require(moveIsAllowed(move));
    require(moveIsWinner(move));
    winners.push(msg.sender);
    require(closeGame());
    emit LogWinningMove(msg.sender, move);
    return true;
   }
}
```

Method 2

```
contract Game {
  address[] public winners;
  function declareWinner(address winner) public onlyOwner returns(bool success) {
    winners.push(winner);
    emit LogWinnerDeclared(msg.sender, winner);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.